# mvc 5 error when update vs 2015 : Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5

My site worked correctly as long as update vs 2015 (new update for update 3 yesterday,'update name: vs14-kb3165756.exe').
after that when i login in my site (in local|Debug Mode), When being transmitted to DefaultUrl (`return Redirect(FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl);`) Page remain loading Give me a few errors over and over After a few minutes of running the program automatically stop debuging
erros are :

> Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured):
>   {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.RemoteDependency","time":"2017-01-26T06:46:04.1521017Z","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"rddf:2.2.0-738","ai.internal.nodeName":"DESKTOP-845R2O1","ai.operation.id":"K6gOUPWhpFk=","ai.location.ip":"::1","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"DESKTOP-845R2O1","ai.operation.name":"GET
>   MYCONTROLLER/Create","ai.operation.parentId":"K6gOUPWhpFk="},"data":{"baseType":"RemoteDependencyData","baseData":{"ver":2,"name":"(localdb)\mssqllocaldb
>   |
>   MYDBNAME","id":"La6kNFeV2fI=","duration":"00:00:00.0020000","resultCode":"0","success":true,"type":"SQL","target":"(localdb)\mssqllocaldb
>   | MYDBNAME","properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true"}}}}

and when disable ApplicationInsights in debug get this error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll

This problem is related to new updates?